# TIMESTAMPDIFF with formatted DATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the TIMESTAMPDIFF function to calculate the difference between two fields - Departure Time and Arrival Time. However, in my query, the columns Departure Time and Arrival Time need to be formatted in such a way: 
    "Jan 4, 2016 - 8:30 AM"

My time stamp function correctly returns the difference between Departure and Arrival Times when used without any formatting. However, as soon as I format it into the above mentioned, my TIMESTAMPDIFF function returns Null.

Any idea how to make this work?[Before date formatting;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR2cD.png) [After Date formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBmLD.png)

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse the date.

Comment: You really should store `DATETIME` in the table, and do the formatting in the display code.

Comment: Post your sql will help.